# how to batch update the unique column based on different condition in a single query mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
======= products table ======
CREATE TABLE `products` ( 
    `id` BigInt( 11 ) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    `item` VarChar( 50 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `category` VarChar( 20 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ),
    CONSTRAINT `unique_item` UNIQUE( `item` ) )
CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;


====== existing data in products table ======
INSERT INTO `products` ( `category`) 
VALUES ( '2' ),( '2' ),( '3' ),( '5' );


====== update batch query ======
UPDATE products
SET item = CASE 
        WHEN category = 2
            THEN 222
        WHEN category = 2
            THEN 211
        WHEN category = 3
            THEN 333
        WHEN category = 5
            THEN 555
        END
WHERE category IN (2, 3, 5) AND item IS NULL
```

I have 3 columns (id, category, item) in products table.
id is primary key and item is unique key.

I want to use a single query to update item at once based on different category. The above update batch query is only working for category 3 and 5. It does not work for category 2.

The error message:

```
Error( 1062 ) 23000: "Duplicate entry '222' for key 'unique_item'"
```

I can use SELECT and UNION to get the list of id and put the id in CASE WHEN for update. But I would like to reduce one step. Is it possible to update all items in one query?

Thanks in advance!

===== EDITED =====

**Current data in the product table**

[image: data in the products table]

**Expected result after run update query**

[image: expected result after update]

Comment: You define Category = 2 twice in your Case statement.  Should Category 2's item be 222 or 211?

Comment: We need to see the data in the `products` table.  And the logic in your `CASE` expression looks off.

Comment: I would suggest that you insert the correct data, rather than updating it after the rows exist.

Comment: @AdamPlocher I edited the original post for my expected result. Thank you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I edited with the screenshots in my original post. Thank you.

Comment: What is the amount of data we are talking about? If it's not thousands of rows, I would just execute one (prepared) UPDATE statement per row in a loop (in a transaction).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want, because `category` is not unique in the table.

You can remove the current rows and insert the values that you really want:

```
delete p from products p
    where category in (2, 3, 5) and itemid is null;

insert into product (itemid, category)
    values ('222', '2' ), ('211', '2' ), ('333', '3' ), ('555', '5' );
```

Comment: existing data in the products table are not allowed to delete. It can have more than one same category in the table with empty value in item column. Only after then will look for empty value in item column and will update accordingly base on the category.

Comment: @ngenge you can add `AND item IS NULL` in the DELETE statement.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel . . . Good point.  It didn't occur to me that categories could have both valid items and `NULL`s (because the sample data has no such examples).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a single query and update all data in one step.

Generate the folowing subquery in PHP from your update data:

```
select 0 as position, 0 as category, 0 as item from dual having item > 0
union all select 1, 2, 222
union all select 2, 2, 221
union all select 1, 3, 333
union all select 1, 5, 555
```

The first line here is only to define the column names and will be removed due to the impossible HAVING condition, so you can easily add the data rows in a loop without repeating the column names.

Note that you also need to define the `position`, which must be sequential for every `category`.

Now you can join it with your `products` table, but first you need to determine the position of a row within the category. Since your server probably doesn't support window functions (`ROW_NUMBER()`), you will need another way. One is to count all products from the same category with a smaller `id`. So you would need a subquery like

```
select count(*)
from products p2
where p2.category = p1.category
  and p2.item is null
  and p2.id <= p1.id
```

The final update query would be:

```
update products p
join (
    select p1.id, ud.item
    from (
        select 0 as position, 0 as category, 0 as item from dual having item > 0
        union all select 1, 2, 222
        union all select 2, 2, 221
        union all select 1, 3, 333
        union all select 1, 5, 555
    ) as ud -- update data
    join products p1
      on  p1.category = ud.category
      and ud.position = (
          select count(*)
          from products p2
          where p2.category = p1.category
            and p2.item is null
            and p2.id <= p1.id
      )
    where p1.item is null    
) sub using (id)
set p.item = sub.item;
```

However I suggest first to try the simple way and execute one statement per row. It could be something like:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    update products
    set item = ?
    where category = ?
      and item is null
    order by id asc
    limit 1
");

$db->beginTransaction();

foreach ($updateData as $category => $items) {
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $stmt->execute([$item, $category]);
        if ($db->rowCount() == 0) {
            break; // no more rows to update for this category
        }
    }
}

$db->commit();
```

I think the performance should be OK for like up to 1000 rows given an index on `(category, item)`. Note that the single query solution might also be slow due to the expensive subquery to determine the position.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL can't make sense of your CASE expression.

You wrote

```
  CASE 
    WHEN category = 2      THEN 222
    WHEN category = 2      THEN 211
```

What do you want to happen when `category` is `2`? You have provided two alternatives, and MySQL can't guess which one you want. That's your duplicate entry.

The error message is admittedly a little confusing.